# Phonegap BarcodeScanner.js can't close on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

thanks for helping !
I'm trying to use the last version of BarcodeScanner (https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/) with ponegap on ios with Xcode 6.2. It works greats and give me the good result when scanning, but when I try to leave camera mode by clicking 'cancel', it does not works ! I have searched everywhere, I can't find a solution :/ 
Here my code (very basic)
**html :**

```
 <body>
    <input type="button" id="scanButton" value="SCAN" />
    <div class="content">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jQuery1.11.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**js**

```
    $("#scanButton").click(function(){
    scanWithCordova();
});

function scanWithCordova(){
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            $('.content').html("We got a barcode\n" +
                  "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                  "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                  "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        }, 
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it from the GIT repo like this:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git
```

It fixed it or me.  I think there are bug fixes that haven't been released in the installable package yet.